# add object inside that single object

Tags: jquery, append, clone, onclicklistener, addition

I have these boxes with the green btn I create a new group with the blue one a new exercise.
When i create a group i also create a blue btn to put the various exercises inside.
The problem is that clicking that button adds an exercise box in all the group boxes and not in the single one. I leave you below the script in jquery so as to have an idea and I am also attaching a photo

```
<script>
$('#addgroup').on("click", function(){
  var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
  var addgro = $('#form-gruppo-vuoto').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx);
  $('.lista-gruppi').append(addgro);
  $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);

  $(".lista-gruppi").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".addesercizio").on("click", function(){
      var form_ids = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
      var addes = $(this).parents().find('#form-esercizio- 
      vuoto').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_ids);
      $(this).parents().find('.lista-esercizi').append(addes);
      $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please structure your question with additional punctuation (and whitespace). Its really hard to read and follow your explanation...

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] which is everything _necessary_ that a reader of your question can reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Don't attach click handlers in your `each loop` like that. You will end up with multiple handlers for every single button, therefore triggering the same event multiple times. Add some rows in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3ogjLuq/2/) and then click on a "row btn" to see what i mean